# After update to Ubuntu 14.04 Eclipse error detection and auto-completion do not work

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, editor, ubuntu-14.04

After the update to Ubuntu 14.04, the error detection and auto-suggestion of Eclipse do not work, or they work in the wrong way.

For example, it does not suggest local variables, like if they are not defined.

Or the dot symbol `.` to access a method (e.g. `myobj.methodName()` ) is considered a wrong token.

The language I am using is Java, and the Eclipse I downloaded has the plugin for Java.

I also updated to Eclipse Luna, but the behaviour is the same.

How is it possible?

Maybe did the upgrade remove some essential package for Eclipse?

Comment: Did you check that in Windows menu -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content assist you have completion inserts enabled? What happens if you do Ctrl+space?

Comment: What do you mean by 'dot symbol is considered a wrong token'? Are you getting an error message? If so what is it?

Comment: Solved. The preferences were missing an option to suggest Java related proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I checked the option *Java type proposal* in Preferences->Content Assist->Advanced